# Issue with rHandsontable dropdown not preserving edits in Shiny app?

Tags: shiny, rhandsontable

I've built a Shiny app that prompts the user for input that are  dynamically added as rows to an rHandsontable. A user can add rows, edit them, and then add more rows. The app is working as it should except for columns created as `hot_col`s with type = 'dropdown'. Whatever edits the user makes to these columns are not preserved through the next time rows are added, but all other edits are.

Below is my app. Edits to the `word` column are preserved, but not to the `color` column created by `hot_col()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        textAreaInput('wordlines', "Enter words separated by newlines"),
        actionButton('submit', "Submit Words"),
        rHandsontableOutput('hot')
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    colors <- c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet")

    build_df <- function(input) {
        data.frame(
            word = unlist(strsplit(input$wordlines, "\n")),
            number = sample(100, 1),
            color = NA,
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
    }

    values <- reactiveValues()

    observeEvent(input$submit, {

        req(input$wordlines)

        if(input$submit == 1) { # if button pressed the first time
            values$df <- build_df(input)
        } else {
            tmp <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
            values$df <- bind_rows(tmp, build_df(input)) # add new rows to values$DF
        }

        updateTextAreaInput(session, 'wordlines', value = "") # clear textAreaInput

        output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
            rhandsontable(values$df, overflow = 'visible') %>% hot_col(col = "color", type = "dropdown", source = colors) # dropdown column which, when edited, should preserve those edits through future adding of rows ('submit' button presses)
            })
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two points you should adjust:

1. Column "color" should be initialized as character.
2. It's bad practice to wrap `render*` functions in `observeEvent`

Here is a working version of your code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    textAreaInput('wordlines', "Enter words separated by newlines"),
    actionButton('submit', "Submit Words"),
    p(),
    rHandsontableOutput('hot')
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  colors <- c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet")

  build_df <- function(input) {
    data.frame(
      word = unlist(strsplit(input$wordlines, "\n")),
      number = sample(100, 1),
      color = NA_character_,
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
  }

  values <- reactiveValues()

  observeEvent(input$submit, {

    req(input$wordlines)

    if(input$submit == 1) { # if button pressed the first time
      values$df <- build_df(input)
    } else {
      tmp <- hot_to_r(input$hot)
      values$df <- bind_rows(tmp, build_df(input)) # add new rows to values$DF
    }

    updateTextAreaInput(session, 'wordlines', value = "") # clear textAreaInput
  })

  output$hot <- renderRHandsontable({
    req(values$df)
    rhandsontable(values$df, overflow = 'visible') %>% hot_col(col = "color", type = "dropdown", source = colors) # dropdown column which, when edited, should preserve those edits through future adding of rows ('submit' button presses)
  })

}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```